# Browser extension to bind clicking on an item of the page to a keyboard shortcut

Tags: web-browser, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a browser extension (Chrome if possible) to spot bind clicking on an item of the page to a keyboard shortcut.

E.g. when browsing a thread on Stack Exchange, I would like to bind the shortcut  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>U</kbd> to the upvote button for the question:

[image: Upvote button for a question on Software Recommendations SE]

I am aware of [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) but:

- it is awkward to condition a Sikuli script so that the shortcut is website-dependent
- element detection in images is a bit slow (~ one second)
- if I have the element to be detected in multiple location (either different monitors or on the same webpage), it would make the Sikuli script even more complex

Comment: Maybe a workaround. Try [Conkeror](http://conkeror.org/) web browser. It maps all clickable links on a page to numbers. You can hit ``f`` to show the numbers and type the corresponding one. If the upvote shortcut is consistent on all pages, then you can map it to Ctrl+U with AutoHotKey

Comment: @Timmy Thanks, this reminds me that I had forgotten to mention the existence of the mouseless browsing add-ons (e.g. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/mouseless-browsing/reviews/) that assign number for each clickable links present in the page. On Conkeror, no number is assigned to the upvote/downvote button :/ (http://i.stack.imgur.com/qkDOc.png) but otherwise it can be good to have it around, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

A shortcut already exists in Stack Exchange.

In your profile page, under Preferences, enable Keyboard Shortcuts

[image]

Pressing `?` to show the help menu reveals:

[image]

The shortcut for voting up is <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>:

[image]

If it's more convenient to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, then it can be mapped using an AutoHotKey command:

```
^u::Send vu
```

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know! However I'm looking for a solution that works for most websites, StackExchange was just one example :-)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I see. But since it's not recognized as a link, I doubt that such a global solution exists. Different websites most likely have different implementations and different shortcuts (if any). I could remove the answer if it's invalid for the scope of your question?

Comment: Let's keep the answer, still useful! I was hoping to find some add-ons that could detect a bit more actionable items than just links.